# Como criar testes unitários junit 5 com @parametrized que retornam objetos

Tags: testes-de-unidade, junit, testes-automatizados, testes-unitarios

Galera vi recentemente o conceito de criar testes com a anotação `@parametrized` no JUnit 5, onde o teste será rodado diversas vezes de acordo com o número de argumentos de entrada. Porém só vi exemplos com string e boolean. Porém se eu tiver o metodo:

```java
public User response(User user) {
    If (username.equals("Luis")) {
        return user;
    } 

    return new User("Maycon");
}
```

Como faço pra fazer um teste pra verificar o retorno com um objeto, baseado na entrada com o objeto usando `@parametrized!`?

Answer (score 0):

Manual oficial do JUnit 5, seção `@ParameterizedTest`: [aqui](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource).

Outro Manual simplificado: [aqui](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#6-method).

Eu realmente não sei o que você quer fazer, mas aqui está um exemplo de uso com 3 parâmetros de entrada e testando um campo e depois o objeto completo.

```java
class MyTestClass {

    private class User {
        // Fields, Constructor, etc.
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object other) {
            // TODO To implement.
        }
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> argumentProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(new User("Toto"), "Luis", "Toto"),
            Arguments.of(new User("Tata"), "Luis", "Tata"),
            Arguments.of(new User("Titi"), "Luis", "Titi"),
            Arguments.of(new User("Joazinho"), "Other", "Maycon")
        );
    }

    public User response(User user, final String username) {
        If (username.equals("Luis")) {
            return user;
        } 

        return new User("Maycon");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("argumentProvider")
    void myTest(final User user, final String username, final String expectedName) {
        final User responseUser = response(user, username);

        // Test de igualdade de campo individual...
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedName, responseUser.getName());

        // Teste de igualdade de objeto...
        // Requer a implementação do método "equals" na classe User.
        Assertions.assertEquals(new User(expectedName), responseUser);
    }
}
```